# Validate XML element with XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MainElement>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>John</name>
    <custom>
        <age>43</age>
        <sex>male</sex>
    </custom>
</MainElement>
```

And another XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MainElement>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Dave</name>
    <custom>
        <age>51</age>
        <county>England</country>
        <city>London</city>
    </custom>
</MainElement>
```

The main structure of both XML files are the same only the `<custom>` element has a different implementation. I already have an XSD file to check the elements like 'id' and 'name' where the `<custom>` element is of the type xs:anyType. Is it possible to create another XSD file which only validates the `<custom>` element without looking to all the other elements that are present?

Comment: The first thing you have to answer is how you are going to figure out which `custom` element you're supposed to get. If you plan on having same tag but with a different content model, then there is no way to do it in XSD 1.0 without custom pre-processing of the XML and dynamic loading of the appropriate XSD (this is called dangling definitions), or use of the xsi:type attribute attached to your custom element. If by "custom" element you mean any named element, things could get easier or more complicated, depending on what constraints you want to have in place. If you can put more details...

Comment: The custom element will always have the name 'custom' and is an optional element. For example, there are three customers who will send there XML file to me and depending on the customer I will need to use the corresponding XSD file to validate all the child elements from the 'custom' element. For all three customers I will use the same XSD to validate the rest of the xml file like the 'id' and 'name' element. Any idea if this can be done with XSD's only or do I need to use other techniques?

Answer (score 0):

I'll illustrate for two customers. First XSD is the base one which is supposed to capture all of the common parts, except for the `custom` which we reference but not define; we leave it "dangling".

Below is the common.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="MainElement">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element ref="custom"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Then we start defining one XSD for each `custom`. For the first XML (custom-1.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="custom">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:unsignedShort"/>
                <xsd:element name="sex" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

And for the second one, custom-2.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="custom">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:unsignedShort"/>
                <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

You then have to create one schema set for each customer by loading the XSDs appropriately: The first set would include the common + custom-1, then common + custom-2, etc.

This is how I would "visualize" these sets using QTAssistant:

[image]

Of course, by itself, the `Common` is invalid.

```
Error occurred while loading [file:///.../validate-xml-element-with-xsd-2.xsd], line 9 position 10.
The 'custom' element is not declared.
```

However, each other collection is valid, since the additional XSD in the set brings into scope the missing definition. Now you can validate each vendor's XML with its associated set. You maintain the integrity of the common definition across vendors, since you do share a common XSD, and you get away with "limitations" in XSD 1.0 using the dangling definition. I think is not really a limitation; it's maybe a "not-so-elegant" approach...

From a processing perspective, you incur the overhead of having the common XSD(s) compiled and loaded as many times as vendors you have.

If this becomes a burden, you could also use another strategy, once the return of preprocessing your XML pays off. You could leave `custom` defined as anyType or even replace it with an xsd:any. Once you validate the common, you extract the node (XSLT or DOM API or a validating reader on top of a DOM node reader, etc.) and validate it independently using the appropriate XSD.

The advantage of the later approach is that you would not have any overhead in terms of XSD. Of course, the trade off may be increased footprint in processing.

XSD 1.1, XSD 1.0 + Schematron, RelaxNG are solutions involving another schema language which have their own advantages and disadvantages. I would think that the above should at least help you understand some of the options you have...

Answer (score 0):

With XSD you can't go with literal meaning of ANY!

So you need to declare all that comes as part of XML .. in one way or other..

I give thumbs-up to your method of using import/include .. that's a clean and allows to extend the requirement further .. but still you should know the possible name of the ANY elements..

Though it's not required, you would be intested to know another method of using `Sequence` and `choice` to achieve your requirement, **with only ONE XSD**

here is the code, that validates both XML1 and XML2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MainElement">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="custom">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              </xs:choice>
              <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="sex" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

this may not be useful for you for now, but may be in future..